# Python Typing with Exception Handling

Tags: python-3.x, exception, type-hinting, mypy

The following code is stored in a file called *sample.py*.

```py
import re
from typing import Optional, Tuple
 
def func(path: str) -> Optional[Tuple[str, str]]:
    regex = re.compile(r"/'([^/']+?)'/'([^/']+?)'")
    try:
        return regex.match(path).groups()
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

The Mypy Python linter throws the following error when analyzing the code:

```py
sample.py:8: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[Sequence[str], Any]", expected "Optional[Tuple[str, str]]")
sample.py:8: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Match[str]]" has no attribute "groups"
```

While `regex.match(path).groups()` may return a `None` type, which does not have a `groups` attribute, the resulting exception is handled and the handling is specified in the return type. However, Mypy does not seem to understand that the exception is being handled. As far as I understand `Optional[Tuple[str, str]]` is the correct return type and Mypy instead insists that the less specific type `Union[Sequence[str], Any]` is correct . What is the proper way to use exception handling with Python typing? (Please, note that I am not asking for alternate ways to write the code without using exception handling. I am just trying to provide a minimal and complete example, where Python type checkers do not behave as  I would expect with exception handling.)

Comment: I also need an answer to this question. For me, the `return` value is `return regex.group(1)` where the function is defined so that it returns `-> Optional[str]:`. And I have an error: `error: Item "None" of "Optional[Match[str]]" has no attribute "group"`. If there is no hit, it returns the `default` which is the argument in the function defined as `default: Any = None`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mypy does not really understand exceptions on a deep level -- in this case, does not understand that since you're catching the AttributeError, it can ignore the "what if `regex.match(path)` is None?" case.

More generally, the fundamental assumption mypy makes is that when you have some object `foo` with type `Union[A, B]` and you do `foo.bar()`, both types `A` and `B` have a `bar()` method.

If only one of those types have a `bar()` method, you'll need to do one of several things:

1. Give mypy sufficient information to narrow down the union to just one of the relevant types before performing the attribute access. For example, isinstance checks, `x is not None` checks...
2. Acknowledge that you are attempting to do something the type checker does not understand and settle for suppressing the generated error. For example, you could cast the type, add on a `# type: ignore` comment, find a way of making `foo` be the dynamic `Any` type...
3. Find a way of redesigning your code to side-step this issue altogether.

(In this particular case, I suppose another alternative might be to submit a pull request to mypy adding support for this pattern. But I'm not sure if this is really feasible: changing any kind of fundamental assumption is difficult work on multiple dimensions.)

Similarly, Mypy also does not understand regexes on a deep level -- e.g. doesn't try and analyze your regex to determine how many groups you'll get and so won't understand your particular regex happens to match strings with exactly two groups. The best it can do is assert that the group will return some unknown number of strings -- hence the type `Sequence[str]` instead of `Tuple[str, str]`.

This sort of limitation is pretty common in type checkers in general, actually: most type systems in mainstream languages don't really support a way to predicate a return type based on the contents of any actual values passed in. Such type systems (dependent type systems, refinement type systems...) are pretty difficult to implement and often have a steep learning curve for end users.

However, it *would* be easier to make mypy support this on a *best-effort* basis by writing a [mypy plugin](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#extending-mypy-using-plugins), if you're up for it. Specifically, try taking a look at `get_method_hook()` and `get_function_hook()`.

Comment: I would add that in the author's case, an isinstance check is likely to be faster to be executed as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/QQFhBZ7.png. Therefore, consider using them when possible as it satisfies mypy and is faster.